# Packages needed for Latex from sagemath

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to export sagemath graphs using these commands:

```
sage: M = Matrix ([ [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0] ])
sage:  # (the order is the number of edges)
sage: G = Graph(M); G.order()
sage: G.show();
sage: latex.engine();
sage: latex(G);
```

my output is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (5.0cm,5.0cm);
%
\definecolor{cv0}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv0}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv0}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv1}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv2}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1v2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
%
\Vertex[style={minimum
size=1.0cm,draw=cv0,fill=cfv0,text=clv0,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\\
hbox{$0$},x=3.6292cm,y=0.0cm]{v0}
\Vertex[style={minimum
size=1.0cm,draw=cv1,fill=cfv1,text=clv1,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\\
hbox{$1$},x=5.0cm,y=5.0cm]{v1}
\Vertex[style={minimum
size=1.0cm,draw=cv2,fill=cfv2,text=clv2,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\\
hbox{$2$},x=0.0cm,y=3.6915cm]{v2}
%
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv0v1,},](v0)(v1)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv0v2,},](v0)(v2)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv1v2,},](v1)(v2)
%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I must be missing some packages to import into TeXstudio because it doesn't recognize `\useasboundingbox`, or `\definecolor` or `\Vertex` or `\Edge`

what packages must I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you need is [tkz-graph](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph).

From the [sage documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_latex.html):

> To use LaTeX in Sage you of course need a working TeX installation and it will work best if you have the `dvipng` and `convert` utilities. For graphs you need the `tkz-graph.sty` and `tkz-berge.sty` style files of the tkz-graph package. TeX, dvipng, and convert should be widely available through package managers or installers. You may need to install the tkz-graph style files in the appropriate locations, a task beyond the scope of this introduction.